# Audio Recorder Player Rails Mobile Friendly

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, flash, audio

**Updated**

I may have found the solution, I can probably make a mobile app with phonegap that talks to my rails app and make a lighter version of a mobile version of the rails app

---

I may be getting an educational rails application to work on soon. The client is an educational consultant, she wants to build a rails application and one of the feature is that a teacher can record a feedback that belongs to a particular student for an assignment. The app needs to be able to record an audio and play an audio.

I have been researching this feature both on stackoverflow and google but I don't find the answers very complete.

I got a couple of options,

1) I have found this blog, a developer built an audio recorder/player with flash http://cykod.com/blog/archive/December2010

and basically its teaching me to grab the audio from a browser with a microphone with flash (needs user permission) and then send it to the server therefore you can escape using red5 (media server).

She wants it to be mobile friendly. I don't think the recording works on the android phone because of flash and I am sure the android phone lacks a microphone. I don't know much about ios either because I don't specialize in mobile. I got my android phone to download flash so it can play the sound.

2) using red5server but I think the player/recorder will still be flash and it doesn't work on the phone

3) http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery and jrecorder

I got some solutions for rails but is there a mobile friendly solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am sure the android phone lacks a microphone

A phone without a microphone would be pretty useless! :)

With Android you can use [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) to record and save an audio file. I'm sure it works, I've done it before.

Although I have never tried, I think you can do it in PhoneGap with the [Capture options](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture) and on iOS with the [Audio Video Foundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/).

That's for the mobile part. You don't need flash there, there are much better options.

---

On your web application, you can surely use Flash to record audio from the computer's microphone.

However, if you're lucky enough your users will use recent browser that support HTML5 audio recording and playback. Check out [capturing audio tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) and libraries such as [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/).

HTH

Comment: hey thanks for the extra info! I never heard of audio.s, the ios audio video foundation framework, and the capturing audio tutorial